# Cache ajax request in dynamic function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a bunch of user friendly formulas (similar to excel) for a form creator site. I have a Lookup function they can use to specify the value they want and the value they are looking up e.g `Lookup(IWantThisVal,ByLookingUpThisVal)`. Through configuration settings in our persistent layer I am able to create this function

```
var formula "return $.ajax({ async: false, cache: true, type: \"get\"," 
        + ("url: \"" + this.strategy.resource + "/\" + " + segments[1].trim() 
        + " + \"/\" + " + segments[0].trim()) + "}).responseText;";

return new Function(formula);
```

There is a little more to it (and I know async is deprecated), but I will spare the details. My problem is getting the `AJAX` call to cache. I tested the function and I see the stored procedure running every time (it is called `onblur`). I am guessing it has to do with being dynamic? Not really sure here since this is new for me.

Comment: Looking at your code i can only say: All of this is wrong. Throw it away, start over. Do not create a system that depends on building strings of source code and evaluating them. This is insane.

Comment: not sure I agree in this case. The application has a module dedicated to parsing excel like functions from form fields into javascript. This example creates the `VLOOKUP` function, which is cached on the server during the form design time so during form input time the ajax call is already created. What you see above uses `dependency injection` to get the API resource and then uses the `segments` variable from the user to get the field key and value to auto populate the form fields

Comment: What I see above is certainly not "dependency injection", it's a completely wrong piece of code that does something you absolutely should not do, *ever*. I'm serious.

Comment: i will point out the obvious that this is only a `snippet` so you don't see that `this.strategy` is `injected` from the constructor of the class.

Comment: That's irrelevant. There is no reason whatsoever to build a function in the way that you do here. It's dangerous to do so. Trust me, instead of trying to convince me. After all, you admit yourself that you have little experience with JS. I've been around the block with JS for a couple of times.

Comment: i didn't mean I was new to javascript when I said that, the issue at hand was something I never came across before. I understand the severity of any dynamic creation, whether it be here or `SQL`. That is why i limit what the user can do under the covers. If there is a better way you would like to discuss please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125125/discussion-between-tomalak-and-jay-michael).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have input fields that `onblur` are making ajax calls, and you only want them to fire when the data in the field has changed?

You could give each `input` a custom html `data-` attribute for the input field like **data-dirty='false'**

The `onchange` event of the textbox would set the attribute to **data-dirty='true'**

The ajax call would only fire if data-dirty='true' for the input element

```
if(myInput.getAttribute('data-dirty')=='true')
{ 
    //fire ajax call
}
```

Reset to data-dirty='false' at the end (success, error) of the ajax call to prevent it from reoccurring each `onblur` event for that field

Comment: yes and since I am using angular I can utilize their data attributes. So is the reason this fires every time because I am using the New Function() call and writing the function dynamically? I guess I want to understand why ajax is firing every time